# How to transpose a triple consisting of triples in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Haskell has a great function *transpose* that transposes a list of (lists) rows into a list of (lists) columns. I.e.:

```hs
transpose[["name","job"],["john","coder"]] 
=>[["name","john"],["job","coder"]]
```

I now need to apply this same principle to a triple consisting of triples, so:

```hs
transpose3 ((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9))
=>((1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9))
```

I cannot use lists instead of the triples. Does anyone have an idea how to achieve this or whether a function like this is already in the Haskell library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the number of items in a tuple are fixed, you can just use pattern matching to unpack the 3-tuples and create a new tuple:

```
transpose3 :: ((a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i)) -> ((a,d,g), (b,e,h), (c,f,i))
transpose3 ((a,b,c), (d,e,f), (g,h,i)) = ((a,d,g), (b,e,h), (c,f,i))
```

So we get as transposed form:

```
Prelude> transpose3 ((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9))
((1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9))
```

The nice thing is that we here can transpose heterogeneous "matrices", and we keep track of the types.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know why I was worried that this solution was too much in the direction of hardcoding, but of course it isn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can convert your 3-tuple to a list, apply transpose and convert resulting list back to a 3-tuple

```
tupleToList (x,y,z) = [x,y,z]
listToTuple [x,y,z] = (x,y,z)

transpose3 xs = listToTuple (map lisToTuple (transpose (map tupleToList (tupleToList xs))))
```

Or convert above function to point free form:

```
transpose3 =  listToTuple.map listToTuple.transpose. map tupleToList.tupleToList
```

This function would work for any size of matrix If your `tupleToList` and `listToTuple` functions are defined appropriately